# Open in the another window using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My map is [here](http://bluewingholidays.com/).

When I click on the separate sections on the map, the target page is opened in the same window. But I want to open it in another window.

```
<iframe 
    src="http://bluewingholidays.com/map/map.html" 
    frameborder="0" 
    scrolling="no"  
    width="500" 
    height="800">

</iframe>
```

This is the whole code of [IFRAME content](http://jsfiddle.net/v7E8h/1/) :

http://jsfiddle.net/v7E8h/1/

How should I change the iframe code to get the desired behavior?

Comment: How are you able to identify different sections in the image?

Comment: <area class="colombo" coords="88,273,106,278,114,272,117,275,117,288,107,287,101,291,90,295,84,276,88,‌​273" href="#colombo" target="_parent" shape="poly" title="Colombo">

Comment: <li class="em"> <a target="_parent" href="ikman.lk/ads-in-colombo"; class="colombo"></a> </li>

Comment: okay, then your target should be "_blank" as Adam Waite suggested.

Comment: i also tried that dear.but same error

Comment: Can you please try with "_top" ?

Comment: this is the whole code http://jsfiddle.net/v7E8h/1/

Answer (score 0):

add attribute `target="_parent"`

that's if I understand what you are asking correctly. Otherwise try `target="_blank"` to the links

You should provide more info though

Comment: <li class="em">
            <a target="_parent" href="http://ikman.lk/ads-in-colombo" class="colombo"></a>
            </li>

Comment: <area class="colombo" coords="88,273,106,278,114,272,117,275,117,288,107,287,101,291,90,295,84,276,88,273" href="#colombo" target="_parent" shape="poly" title="Colombo">

Comment: are you wanting to click a link from within the iframe to open in the browser window? or open a new tab in the browser window? More importantly, have you got control of the iframe content?

Comment: yes.i want to open another windows for separate map when click on it .yes dear i have the control of the iframe content